# Set Kiosk mode in Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to set the `--kiosk` and the `--kiosk-printing` flags in Chrome for Android on my Galaxy Tab 10.1.

All the instructions that I can find here and elsewhere tell me to go to `chrome://flags` and set the flag there. But neither of these flags is mentioned in the list there.

What do I need to do to set kiosk mode?

I'm using Chrome 39.0.2171.56 on Android 4.0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) suggests you can put them in /data/local/tmp/content-shell-command-line.

eg `adb shell 'echo "chrome --kiosk --kiosk-printing" > /data/local/tmp/content-shell-command-line'`

Comment: Can somebody explain what this does. When I execute I get nothing in that directory and the flags don't appear in 'about:version' in Chrome.

Comment: If the flags appear in about:version then it should switch Chrome to kiosk mode - ie full screen with silent printing. I must confess I gave up on Chrome and switched to Firefox with a full-screen add-on for my kiosk device.

Comment: Ok, do you need root to add the flags? Thanks.

Comment: I presume the flags are set at build time, or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: On Chrome for Android on my side it was: ```adb shell 'echo " --kiosk --kiosk-printing <url>"  > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line'```. It now appears in ```chrome://version``` however, the kiosk-printing is still not working.

Comment: Is it possible to build an APK to setup this so `adb shell` isn't needed? I cannot edit the file with Termux, what can I do?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to do this in Chrome on Android; you can achieve what you want to with [Kiosk Browser Lockdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.procoit.kioskbrowser) instead.

Comment: Thanks very much NStorm. I don't see any reference to --kiosk-printing in the docs for that app. Do you know if it's possible to enable this (or some other way to print directly to the printer via the browser without user interaction)?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the app.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to add flags to chrome on Android unless they exist in the  chrome://flags a list.