# Android Kiosk Mode

Tags: kiosk-mode

It would be great if someone can verify my current understanding of the Android Kiosk mode:

In earlier versions than Android 5.0 there is no comparable function like the Pin Screen (turning your device into a kiosk mode) - at least not out of the box from the standard functionality of the operating system.

Since Android 5.0 we have the pin screen function which allows us to specify the use of only one app (without leaving it or doing anything else except using this app). If you choose google chrome as the app of your choice (for the kiosk mode) there is no way to prevent the user from changing websites. Is that correct?

What we want to do:
We developed a website which shall run on Android devices in Google Chrome. We want to put this specific website into a kiosk mode. The problem we think we will have is that the user can still change the url and therefore leave our website.

Do you know if there is any way to prevent that?
And are we right that before Android 5 no kiosk mode exists?

Comment: If it's a public retail display then it's very much a thing that you have to worry about, especially if the devices will have little to no supervision from employees or stakeholders. Another use is for restricting employees from using the devices for personal use, if they are meant for work-related use only.

Comment: Related: [Set Kiosk mode in Chrome for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/88031/44325)

Answer (score 2):

[AirWatch Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airwatch.browser) could be exactly what you're looking for - you can whitelist URLs and landing pages so you don't navigate away from your preferred page. I don't believe the native Android browser or Chrome have those kinds of options.

Comment: If anyone finds this answer useful, they may look at [Surelock Kiosk Browser Lockdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surefox&hl=en). I've not tested it, neither I'm affiliated to it, but its description appears to be on the lines this answer is.