# Lock tablet to run ONLY a webpage on chrome fullscreen

Tags: chrome-for-android, notification-bar, navigation-bar

I have created a software for restaurants. Some restaurants have tablets on each table so that their customer can order food/drink without a waiter. I have finished coding my software, and now I have another task:

Each tablet (for example, Galaxy A7 Tab Lite), must run my local app on chrome (for example, http://192.168.1.100:3000)

Problem is: Chrome showing the tabs, the bottom navigation bar and user can access the settings through the notifications bar, enable/disable wifi, etc, such as in these images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As the tablet's use will be for the user to only access my webpage (so he can order food/drinks), the web page should be:

1. full screen, so that the tabs view do not appear
2. navigation bar and notifications bar should be locked/disabled

I've tried [THIS](https://techwithtech.com/full-screen-chrome-android/) tutorial for fullscreen. I tried adding my website to the Home screen, but when I clicked, it would just open as a regular tab, no fullscreen mode.

The reason for that is (as funny as it may sound) that in some restaurants, some kids were able to exit the application and were downloading games to the tablet, were watching Netflix, were adding their photo as the Android's background image, etc. The user has to interact only with my web app.

So, is there a way to achieve this? Maybe some Android settings, chrome tweaking, third party apps, custom ROM?

Comment: Look for kiosk mode.

Comment: [Kiosk mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. There are some questions that are related/possible dupes: [Set Kiosk mode in Chrome for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/88891/44325), [Android Kiosk Mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/115258/44325). Please try and let us know the result, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewT. That's exactly what I was looking for, but I would never have guessed that the name for it was "Kiosk". Thank you Rohit and beeshyams for pointing me to the right direction and AndrewT for welcoming me and sharing these links

Answer (score 3):

You can try my app [WebLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simionescu.vlad.weblock).

It won't disable the notifications bar but there's not much that can be done with it. To go to Settings for example, you have to type the password. There's no way to bypass it since the phone is locked. They can go to the usual lock screen and back to the app but nothing else.

[edit] I just posted a new version on Google Play, it addresses the issue I mentioned before with the compatibility with newer Android devices. Now every device should be able to install it, regardless of Android version.