# How to set an Android tablet so that it is not possible to exit a Chrome tab?

Tags: chrome-for-android, tablet

We need to set up an Android tablet so that it can only be used to browse a Chrome tab set by us. It must not be possible for the user to exit Chrome or do anything other than fill in the fields of the web page opened in the Chrome tab. Can anyone tell us how this can be done?

We just searched on google for a solution with no success.

Comment: Unless I'm wholly off on this the solution is a dedicated app which should load a given page in webview and makes sure the webview cannot be closed. The app also needs to set itself as a default home launcher app so that home button presses doesn't dismiss the app. You might want to look into Kiosk type app to see if they provide the features you need. Else you might have to get somebody to develop a custom app for this.

Comment: Possibly related (but old): [Set Kiosk mode in Chrome for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/88031/44325)

Comment: Kiosk seems a possible answer to this problem. I’ll keep you updated about it.